# Index out of bound exception between Java and JNI (dll)

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays, dll

I have programmed a dll for a java application of mine. One of the methods from the dll acquire some float values, store them in an array and, in the end, it sends the array to the java application. My problem is that, when I try to store the result from the native method in an array located in the Java layer, the index out of bound exception is thrown. Here are some parts from the code:

```
    //note: MyClass is a static class...
    public static void javaMethod() {
        float[] Aux = new float[6];
        Aux = MyClass.NativeMethod(); //error (index out of bounds exception)
        System.arraycopy(MyClass.NativeMethod(), 0, auxArray, 0, 6); //fails as well

    }

JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_Package_MyClass_NativeMethod
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass cls)
{
    jfloatArray JNIArray = env->NewFloatArray(6);
    if(JNIArray == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    {
        float * temp;
        temp = &gobalArray[i]; //let's say that this is a float array with 6 elements...
        env->SetFloatArrayRegion(JNIArray, i, 6, temp);
    }
    return JNIArray;
}
```

There are no problems during the execution of the dll method, but I guess that I may have forgotten an important command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`env->SetFloatArrayRegion(JNIArray, l, 6, temp);` is trying writing `6` floats every time. Make it `1`. Also, I have assumed second argument to be `i` instead of **`l`**.